# Scala - calculate two variables in one step

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am assigning two variables:

```
val a: Seq[Int] = schema.map(_.getLong(key="width").toInt)

val b: Seq[String] = schema.map(_.name)
```

I use these variables at different places.

As I am computing both from the same schema, I need to merge this into one step with one variables so that I can compute this in one attempt.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val ab= schema.map(i=> (i.getLong(key="width").toInt),i.name))
```

would give you a tuple with both values

if you want them named you can

```
case class S(name : String, width: Int)
val ab = schema.map(i=> S(i.name,i.getLong(key="width").toInt))
```

Answer (score 2):

> `I need to merge this into one step with one variables so that I can compute this in one attempt.`

you can create `Seq[Tuple2[Int, String]]` as

```
val c: Seq[(Int, String)] = schema.map(x => (x.getLong(key="width").toInt, x.name))
```

so that `c._1` is equal to your *a elements* and `c._2` is equal to the *elements of b*

or in other words

*`c.map(_._1)` is equal to a* and *`c.map(_._2)` is equal to b*